# Laravel Stapler ,Working on User::create but not on update

Tags: php, laravel-5

In Form Add in my controller

```
        public function add()
        {
            $input = Input::all();
            $validator = Validator::make( $input, User::$rules['create'] ); # Or User::$rules['create']
       if ( $validator->fails() ) {
        return "failure";
        }
                else{          
                return User::create(Input::all());  
                }

        }
```

In Form Edit in m controller

```
        public function edit()
        {
         $input = Input::all();
        $validator = Validator::make( $input, User::$rules['edit'] ); # Or User::$rules['create']
       if ( $validator->fails() ) {
        return "failure";
        }
                else{
                    $user=new User();
                        $user->find(1);
            $user->update(Input::all());  
                }

        }
```

In User Model

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password','role','position','mobile_number','picture','facebook','twitter','instagram','linkedin','avatar'];
public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
        $this->hasAttachedFile('avatar', [
            'styles' => [
                'medium' => '300x300',
                'thumb' => '100x100'
            ],

                        'url' => '/uploads/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
            'default_url' => '/uploads/defaults/:style/missing.png'
        ]);

        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
```

This code works well for Adding a new user but its shows the error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;avatar&#039; in &#039;field list
```

I have the required fields in the user table and every thing works well on the `User::create`

Edited:Here is my dd($user)
http://pastebin.com/4e3HSusG

Comment: Do you see field avatar if you print the $user object with dd($user) before applying the update?

Comment: Here is addintion error information in sql error (SQL: update `users` set `id` = 3, `name` = Suhass, `email` = suhas@gmail.com, `password` = y$Qek8MBiKnW443wQmvp8bjeFHfErUlW6W679zzQhfzi7ODQ1AZ/2mi, `mobile_number` = 9999999999, `role` = Admin, `position` = Web Developer, `facebook` = , `twitter` = , `instagram` = , `linkedin` = , `avatar` = C:\wamp2015\tmp\phpAC0A.tmp, `updated_at` = 2015-04-24 10:19:57)

Very thanks for your response here is my dump data http://pastebin.com/4e3HSusG
i

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution from different thread

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->update(Input::except('avatar'));
$user->avatar = Input::file('avatar');
```